# Is Dragon Ball Heroes Goku Ultra Instinct way stronger than Dragon Ball Super Goku Ultra Instinct?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-heroes

In the preview for episode 6 of Dragon Ball Heroes we see Goku UI handling Super Saiyan 3 Cumber.

[image]

This is the same Goku who fused with Vegeta fought Cumber before. When Goku was fused with Vegeta, they used kaioken times 50 IIRC. And they were fighting Cumber in base form, which is 50x2x4 = 400 times weaker. This means Cumber SSJ3 is (400x50) 20000 times stronger than Vegito Super Saiyan Blue. And this Cumber SSJ3 was being handled by an unfused Goku Ultra Instinct. Now according to Wiss, fusion multiplies the power of the warriors "tens of times". That's at the very least a times 20 multiplier. Assuming this lower bound for the sake of the math, that makes Super Saiyan Blue Goku to be at the very least 20x20000 = 400000 times weaker than Cumber SSJ3. But then Goku Ultra Instinct was handling Cumber SSJ3, so the multiplier from Super Saiyan Blue to Ultra Instinct in Dragon Ball Heroes has to be at the very least 400,000. And it could be much more. If the fusion multiplies by 50, it would be 1,000,000 . If the fusion multiplies by 100, it would be 2,000,000 . Now, this doesnt look at all as the power boost Goku got in Dragon Ball Super from Super Saiyan Blue to Ultra Instinct. Then my question is, is Dragon Ball Heroes Goku Ultra Instinct way stronger than Dragon Ball Super Goku Ultra Instinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're reading too much into this.

First, consider that **Dragon Ball Heroes is a non-canon promotional anime**. The scenarios within aren't necessarily supposed to be consistent, they're just supposed to be cool and promote the game, Dragon Ball Heroes. Because of this, it makes the most sense for Goku to go through all of his forms before gaining the upper hand on Cumber. This includes all of his Super Saiyan forms, as well as Vegito and Ultra Instinct.

As well, consider that **Akira Toriyama has never been totally consistent** with the exact strength that the Super Saiyan transformations grant to their users, and he has been inconsistent in general with how strong characters are throughout the series. For example, back when DBZ: Battle of Gods was released, Akira Toriyama stated that in terms of power, Super Saiyan God **Goku** was a **6**, **Beerus** was a **10**, and **Whis** a **15** ([source](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/translations/battle-gods-animanga-akira-toriyama/)). If this were still true, SSJ Blue Kaioken x20 Goku should absolutely destroy both Beerus and Whis at the same time. Clearly, this was just a rough idea he had, and it was retconned as Dragon Ball Super continued.

To answer your specific question, I would say that **it's impossible to judge the strength of Dragon Ball Heroes Goku relative to Dragon Ball Super Goku**. Dragon Ball Heroes is not concerned with coherence and consistency as much as it is cool scenarios, and thus, characters will be as strong or weak as the plot needs them to be.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, the answer to your question is a definite Yes. Dragon ball Heroes Characters are multiple times stronger than characters from any of the canon series. Secondly, The Dragon Ball Heroes Power levels are completely inconsistent and Broken**. The strength of the characters are completely adjusted solely for the sake of plot, so I suggest you don't take anything seriously. The reason I say this is for example recently

- We first see SSJB Goku fight SSJ4 Xen Goku. In the manga, SSJB Goku ends up victorious making him the stronger off the two.
- We see Base Cumber holding his own against SSJB+Kaioken Vegito(Which is technically 2 SSJB Vegito's).
- Then we see Goku turning SSJG and attemption to fight Cumber and actually trades a few blows with him which makes no sense.
- Then we see, SSJ4 Xeno Vegito being strong enough to overpower SSJ3 Cuber who is 400 times stronger than Base Cumber SSJ4 Xeno Vegito should be weaker than SSJB Vegito and SSJB +Kaioken Vegito should be way stronger

Answer (score 0):

In Episode 9 when Goku returns he does not use mastered UI, he fully "Masters" Omen UI apparently and could use that form at will. And when he was attacking it was like he uses the power of MUI when he attacks for a brief second. So that  yea SDBH  UI is stronger

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. As it stands, I'm not sure it provides enough proof to support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes dbh Goku is leagues above anyone in dbs. capsule corp Goku (who isn't the same as dbs Goku considering cc Goku knows turles who dbs goku doesnt) fought Xeno goku and gave him a challenge, this already puts his attack potency at multiverse lvl- complex multiverse lvl due to xeno goku managing to fight demigra who was going to destroy infinite timelines. In dbs the strongest feat ever performed was Zeno erasing a timeline, that timeline would contain all 12-18 universes making Zeno low multiversal, until Zeno shows greater feats, he caps at that level, and dbs goku scales nowhere near to Zeno in terms of attack potency and destructive capability meaning base capsule corp goku would be more than enough to wash dbs mui goku. Now im using vs battle wiki tiers, if u want to put Zeno at multiversal that's fine but that still doesn't change the outcome of the fight due to people in heroes scaling higher into multiverse lvl than dbs.

Comment: Xeno Goku can be Low-Complex Multiversal, not Complex Multiversal. DBH does not have dimensions beyond 5 or 6. However this isn't a power scaling post

Answer (score 0):

KK doesn't multiply SSJ Blue. KK only multiplies regular ki (base form power) and then adds it to the SSJS whatever form Goku is. KK x20 (baseform) + SSJ + any divine state. Goku's power will only increase 1 or 2% since divine ki is way bigger than regular ki.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For one, Dragon Ball Heroes follows events from TOEI anime and Xenoverse timelines, so it is in fact VERY different to canon DBS when it comes to power scaling or even consistency in general. All of the above simply means that Dragon Ball Heroes characters are leagues stronger than anyone in Super. Take for example Mechikabura who was able casually create a Black Hole in his hand that absorbed all possible timelines, which there are widely considered to be infinite of. The same Mechikabura was one-shotted by Trunks in the DBH manga, which happened way before these current events. Compare that to DBS, the best feat is Zeno destroying just 1 single timeline. There's also Fuu absorbing DogiDogi's power, a bird which is similar to TokiToki that controls space-time across all timelines, and then battling Universal Tree Goku, all of these are showing way beyond anything in DBS so far including the manga.

So yes, DBH characters in general are simply much more powerful just by virtue of being a DBH character, as silly as that sounds, but Dragon Ball power scaling is rarely not silly.